# Writing IIS URL rewrite rules

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I am using the IIS7 URL Rewrite module. I want to create a rule that matches this:

http://www.example.com/test123.

but not this:

http://www.example.com/test123/

Comment: is the full stop mark (`.`) in the first URL part of it?

Answer (score 0):

Is something like http://www.mydomain.com/test123/bla allowed?

If not:

```
^[^/]+$
```

If yes:

```
^.*[^/]$
```